# Can a woman offer prayer of janazah?

Tags: salat, women, funeral

Sayyiduna Abu Hurayrah (radiyallahu ‘anhu) reports that Rasulullah (sallallahu ‘alayhi wa sallam) said:

“Whoever attends the funeral procession and offers the Janazah Salah, will get a reward equal to one ‘qirat’, and whoever accompanies it till burial, will get a reward equal to two ‘qirats’. It was asked, “What are two qirats?” He answered, “Like two huge mountains.”

(Sahih Bukhari, Hadith: 1325 and Sahih Muslim, Hadith: 945).                                                                                                         So my question is ,can a woman offer janazah salah and accompany it till burial ?

Comment: What is "mud"? Your title question has already an answer which you would find easier if you used related tags instead of tags that neither are about janaza nor women nor death. I've edited them by now!

Answer (score 0):

You may check this fatwa
https://islamqa.info/en/answers/14522/ruling-on-women-praying-the-janaazah-funeral-prayer
May Allah give us knowledge

Comment: Jazakallah khair